# Elementary Queing/Probability Theory Question

Tags: probability, optimization

Mathematically, given a stochastic process, where a customer arrives every minute, and 10% of them have a large amount of items (5-minute processing time) while 90% have a small amount of items (30-second processing time), what is the optimal processing strategy to minimize average processing time and ensure fairness? The definition of fairness is left up for interpretation.

Initially, I just thought that it would be the optimal and fairest strategy to simply alternate large and small customers. However, I have no way to prove this. I am mainly struggling on how to define "fair."

Comment: If it is one single file queue with single point servixe, there is no question of optimising the process, and with no definition of "fairness" there is no way to make the process "fair". First come first served is less likely to cause resentment among customers in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

A natural aim would be to minimise the average queueing time over all customers (or equivalently, to minimise the average queue-length over time).

Suppose we are dealing with a single server. We can distinguish two cases. In the "non-preemptive" case, a service must be continued through to completion once it has been started. In the "preemptive" case, a service can be interrupted (in order to serve another customer) and resumed later. As in your description, assume that the service time of each job is known as it enters the system.

The policies which minimise average queueing time are [Shortest job first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_job_next) (in the non-preemptive case) and [Shortest remaining time first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_remaining_time) (in the pre-emptive case).

Under both these policies, longer jobs have  a longer average queueing time (excluding their own service time) than shorter jobs do. Whether or not this is "fair" is a matter of interpretation....